# What is happening inside the for loop with grade and sum? I have no clue what it's doing

Tags: java, bluej

This is a program that calculates the users test average based on how many inputs he wants. But, I do not know what is happening inside the for loop and what it means. The grade and the sum.

```
   System.out.println("Welcome, please type your first name. ");
   String name = scan.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Welcome, please type your last name. ");
   String last = scan.nextLine();
   int numberOfTests;
   System.out.println("How many tests would you like the average of?");
   numberOfTests = scan.nextInt();

   while(numberOfTests<0)
   {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        System.out.println("How many tests would you like the average 
        of?");
        numberOfTests = scan.nextInt();
   }
   double sum = 0;
   double grade;
   System.out.println("Enter " + numberOfTests + " scores.");
   for(int i = 0;i<numberOfTests;i++)
   {
    grade = scan.nextDouble();
    sum += grade;
   }
   double average = (sum/numberOfTests);
   System.out.println("Okay " + name.charAt(0) + last.charAt(0) + ", your 
   average score is " + (average));
   System.out.print("Your letter grade is ");
```

The program works.

Comment: asking user to input grade of each test and summing the numbers of all test.

Comment: `sum += grade;` is essentially `sum = sum + grade;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `scan` is an instance of [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). This class is used to read from user input, so `grade = scan.nextDouble()` reads the next `double` from the user's input.

Then `sum += grade` is equivalent to `sum = sum + grade`; it adds the `grade` that the user input to the total grade (`sum`).

So the loop asks for `numberOfTests` inputs from the user, and adds them all together in `sum`.

For details for how the input is read, look at [the documentation for `Scannner#nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--).

Answer (score 0):

```
grade = scan.nextDouble();
```

This asks the user to input a grade(a double type number)

```
sum += grade;
```

Then for each iteration, the input grade is added to sum. So after `numberOfTests` iterations, sum will contain the sum of `numberOfTests`  grades.
As mentioned by @Goion in comments, `sum += grade;` is basically `sum = sum + grade;`
Once you have the sum, you can divide it by `numberOfTests` to get the average.

The for loop is used here to calculate the sum of all the grades.

Answer (score 0):

What this code does, it asks you to enter numbers according to the total of `numberOfTests`. Having, `i = 0` you enter 2. `i = 1` you enter 3. And the sum variable will be accumulating: `2 + 3`.

```
System.out.println("Enter " + numberOfTests + " scores.");
for(int i = 0;i<numberOfTests;i++){
    grade = scan.nextDouble();
    sum += grade;
}
```

At the end, sum will be equal to `5`.

And finally

```
double average = (sum/numberOfTests);
```

`average = 5/2` is equal to 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
numberOfTests = scan.nextInt();
```

Here asking how many tests they want to enter marks. If input value less than 0 asking the value again.
below for loop used to read the number of makes based on the previous input test value
and adding all enter marks

```
for(int i = 0;i<numberOfTests;i++)
   {`enter code here`
}
```

below statement calculate the average marks (simple calculation total marks / no. of tests)

```
double average = (sum/numberOfTests);
```